linux sendfile sometimes reports EPIPE
I am writing a small file server. I was using the usual read/write but am now experimenting with sendfile(2).
Even though it works fine 100% of the time and I see a nice 2x speed improvement, sometimes (roughly 1/5 times) sendfile() returns -1 with errno set to EPIPE. OS is ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS kernel 5.4.0. Here is the key code snippet (setup and error checking removed for brevity):
    int sock_fd = accept (svr_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_socket, &cli_len);
    const char *filename = "myfile";
    int file_fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY);
    struct stat stat_buf;
    fstat (file_fd, &stat_buf);
    size_t n_sent = 0;
    ssize_t n_s = 0;
    while ((n_s = sendfile (sock_fd, file_fd, NULL, stat_buf.st_size - n_sent)) > 0)
        n_sent += n_s;
    if (n_s < 0)
        printf ("%s: sendfile: %ld <? %ld %s\n", filename, (long)n_sent, (long)stat_buf.st_size, strerror(errno)

Typical output shows n_sent is always < the file size even though I know for certain the client always receives the complete file:
myfile: 390892 <? 1742522 Broken pipe

The man page doesn't even list EPIPE as a possible errno.
So either 1) I am doing something wrong or 2) sendfile is buggy.
Comments please! Thanks in advance.

I don't know exactly when this was fixed but the problem does not occur in ubuntu 24.04 LTS running kernel 6.8.0.
